NG0203 injection problem when building multi-project app
I have a multi project app in angular.
I've added config files to one of the inner project
and get NG0203 inject() must be called from an injection context when trying to load the route I'm going to.
This only happens with the project I actually recreated to be standalone apps. I added preserverSymslinks:true but nothing works.
Please let me know if you need certain config files.
I think the multi project app is called a mono repoo. I've added package.json to it also node_modules etc... in order it to be individualized.Apparently I shoudln't do that but I didn't found a way to do it differently.it works when using ng serve
here is the stacktrace:
ERROR RuntimeError2: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
    at injectInjectorOnly2 (webiste.com/main.js:87261:11)
    at ɵɵinject2 (https://website/main.js:87271:61)
    at Object.factory (https://website.com/main.js:100987:45)
    at https://website.com/main.js:26562:35
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (https://website/main.js:25201:5)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (https://website.com/main.js:26561:11)
    at R3Injector.get (https://website/main.js:26454:23)
    at definition.getStandaloneInjector (https://website.com/main.js:100994:27)
    at ComponentFactory.create (https://website.com/main.js:33069:53)
    at ViewContainerRef2.createComponent (https://website.com/main.js:33380:43)

angular.son
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "synestez.io": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/synestez.io",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob":"**/*",
                "input":"projects/sequencer/src/assets/",
                "output":"/assets/"
              },{
                "glob":"**/*",
                "input":"projects/store/src/assets/",
                "output":"/assets/"
              },{
                "glob":"**/*",
                "input":"projects/dj-mixer/src/assets/",
                "output":"/assets/"
              },{
                "glob":"**/*",
                "input":"projects/worklet-generator/src/assets/",
                "output":"/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/sequencer/src/styles.scss",
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/styles.scss",
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/styles.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "projects/sequencer/src/assets/styles/",
                "projects/dj-mixer/src/assets/styles/",
                "projects/worklet-generator/src/assets/styles/"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "fileReplacements":[ {
                "replace":"src/environments/environments.ts",
                "with":"src/environments/environment.production.ts"
              } ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "optimization": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "fileReplacements":[
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environments.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "staging"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "synestez.io:build:production"
            },
            "staging": {
              "buildTarget": "synestez.io:build:staging"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
          "styles": [
            "projects/sequencer/src/styles.scss",
            "src/styles.scss"
          ],
          "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
            "includePaths": [
              "projects/sequencer/src/assets/styles/",
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/assets/styles/",
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/assets/styles/"
            ]
          },"assets": [
            "src/favicon.ico",
            "src/assets",
            {
              "glob":"**/*",
              "input":"projects/sequencer/src/assets/",
              "output":"/assets/"
            },{
              "glob":"**/*",
              "input":"projects/store/src/assets/",
              "output":"/assets/"
            },{
              "glob":"**/*",
              "input":"projects/dj-mixer/src/assets/",
              "output":"/assets/"
            },{
              "glob":"**/*",
              "input":"projects/worklet-generator/src/assets/",
              "output":"/assets/"
            }
          ]
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "synestez.io:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest",
          "options": {
            "preserveSymlinks":true,
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "store": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/store",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/store/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/store",
            "index": "projects/store/src/index.html",
            "browser": "projects/store/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "projects/store/src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/store/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/store/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/store/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/store/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "store:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "store:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "store:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/store/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/store/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/store/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/store/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "sequencer": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/sequencer",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/sequencer/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/sequencer",
            "index": "projects/sequencer/src/index.html",
            "browser": "projects/sequencer/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/sequencer/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/sequencer/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/sequencer/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/sequencer/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "sequencer:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "sequencer:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "sequencer:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/sequencer/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/sequencer/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/sequencer/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/sequencer/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "dj-mixer": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/dj-mixer",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/dj-mixer/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/dj-mixer",
            "index": "projects/dj-mixer/src/index.html",
            "browser": "projects/dj-mixer/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/dj-mixer/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",

          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "dj-mixer:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "dj-mixer:build:development"

            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "dj-mixer:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/dj-mixer/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/dj-mixer/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "worklet-generator": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/worklet-generator",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/worklet-generator/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/worklet-generator",
            "index": "projects/worklet-generator/src/index.html",
            "browser": "projects/worklet-generator/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/worklet-generator/tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "worklet-generator:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "worklet-generator:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "worklet-generator:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "src/polyfills.ts",
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "projects/worklet-generator/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/worklet-generator/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


how about actual code and (most probably present) stacktrace instead?

Deminify and try again

@Antoniossss thanks for your concern I've added the stacktrace.I think putting the code won't help in that case, I strongly think this is a configuration problem.Apparently mono-repo shouldn't be set as individual angular projects in the usual way and I think the problem comes from there. I have a conventionnal project in my mono-repo (no package.json) and the import works fine. I will add the angular.json

@Antoniossss what do you mean by deminify?

use  "optimization": false,  so the stacktrace would be human readable, as you have a problem in at tOe main.js:101:2364 will not help you a lot.

@Antoniossss the exact unreadable output comes when I set sourceMap:true

sourcemaps are not magic, you would have to translate stacktrace first using sourceMap.... therfore, disable minification so no source map is needed in the first place.

@Antoniossss I've updated my stacktrace

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

do you have any inject(... in your code?

@grenobnik yes but that doesn't come from there. my inject are well placed and ng serve works well.Thanks for trying to help
